# Null property in Vue layout component even when guarding with v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm having issues trying to access a property from within a component which is part of my `default.vue` layout. The component is called `NavBar` and it's using a `Vuex` store property called `Navigation` which provides the navigation structure for the site.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'document' of null
```

With `null` being what is meant to be `Navigation` retrieved as such (in `default.vue`):

```
<template>
    ...
        <n-link :to="linkResolver(navigation.document)" class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img class="h-8 w-8" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-300.svg" alt="Workflow">
        </n-link>
    ...
</template>

...

<script lang="ts">

...

export default {
    name: 'NavBar',
    data() {
        return {
            linkResolver: linkResolver
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['navigation'])
    }
}
```

In `index.vue` (the homepage), I am fetching this `navigation` object from the Prismic API via the `async fetch()` method, and upon completion, setting it in my Vuex store (the getter above retrieves this value).

Interestingly, the code works fine if I move the `NavBar` component to within `index.vue`, so it appears that `default.vue` is trying to access the property before it has been loaded. I therefore assumed that adding `v-if="navigation"` would resolve the problem, however it doesn't.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there something unique about `Vue` layouts vs. pages that could be causing this?

FYI, I'm using `Nuxt`.

Comment: Have you tried `:to="linkResolver(navigation ? navigation.document : {})"` ?

Comment: This works, but would it be considered bad practice? Is this not exactly what `v-if` should be used for?

Comment: If v-if on n-link didn't help, the only thing that could make sense to me is that args (navigation.document) are bind(like .bind()) to linkResolver internally(nuxt?) so it is not executed, but accessed(with error) during binding. Traceback could be helpful.

Comment: `v-if` specifies whether a component should be rendered or not - it does not specify or limit what values can you provide as props values. A good practice is to always check whether the object whose properties/keys you are trying to access actually exists - or is NULL/undefined.